# How to add SVG element from String to DOM

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to add SVG which includes rect and use tags from a string to the DOM.

I doesn't seams to work the way I do.

```js
  var documentAsString =
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
   <document xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\
    <svg id="container" >\
     <g xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">\
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/>\
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#shape" x="200" y="50" fill="blue"></use>\
     </g>\
    </svg>\
   </document>\
  ';
  
  var newDocument = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(documentAsString, "text/xml");
  var container = newDocument.getElementById("container");
  var useContainer = document.getElementById('use-container');

  useContainer.removeChild(useContainer.firstElementChild);
  useContainer.appendChild(container.getElementsByTagName('g')[0]);
```

```html
 <svg>
  <defs>
   <g id="shape">
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
   </g>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#shape" x="50" y="50" />
  <g id="use-container" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" fill="red"></rect>
  </g>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SVG element needs to be in the svg namespace i.e. have an xmlns attribute with the appropriate value...

```js
  var documentAsString =
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
   <document xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="container" >\
     <g xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">\
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/>\
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#shape" x="200" y="50" fill="blue"></use>\
     </g>\
    </svg>\
   </document>\
  ';
  
  var newDocument = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(documentAsString, "text/xml");
  var container = newDocument.getElementById("container");
  var useContainer = document.getElementById('use-container');

  useContainer.removeChild(useContainer.firstElementChild);
  useContainer.appendChild(container.getElementsByTagName('g')[0]);
```

```html
 <svg>
  <defs>
   <g id="shape">
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
   </g>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#shape" x="50" y="50" />
  <g id="use-container" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" fill="red"></rect>
  </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Ok, do you have an explanation for that? Is it because `container.getElementsByTagName('g')[0]` won't be treated as a SVG Element?

Comment: That's how XML works. You need to tell the XML parser that the svg tag is SVG and not some other markup's tag. It's how the XML parser distinguishes between an SVG `<a>` tag and an html `<a>` tag for instance. html on the other hand has a parser that infers the namespace from the context.